# No voice input-- microphone (unplugged) 16.04

Tags: nvidia, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Internal mic stopped working even after fresh install. Any ideas.
---------------------------------------------------------------/

```
$ sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: CX20561 Analog [CX20561 Analog]

  Subdevices: 1/1

  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia

                      HDA NVidia at 0xfc480000 irq 21
```

--------------------------------------------------------------/

~$ sudo cat /etc/modules

/etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.

This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded

at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

--------------------------------------------------------------/

~$ uname -a

Linux alaa-HP-Pavilion-dv2700-Notebook-PC 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:46:42 UTC 2018 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

-----------------------------------------------------------------------/

[image]

Comment: Does your bios have any sound settings?

Comment: Vendor: Hewlett-Packard.  Version: F.28